# PHP Two Way Encryption

Tags: php, encryption

I need to be able to encrypt and decrypt a variable, however I also need to know if the decryption was successful. In my code, when I change the `$string` variable before decryption to something else, I receive random characters.

```
function encrypt($string) {
    $key = 'password';
    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
    return $encrypted;
}
function decrypt($encrypted) {
    $key = 'password';
    $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
    return $decrypted;
}

$string = 'Hello world.';
if (encrypt($string)) {
    $string = encrypt($string);
    echo $string;
    echo '<br>';
}

if (decrypt($string)) {
    $string = decrypt($string);
    echo $string;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Is it possible to detect failed decryption?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a "failed" encryption?

Comment: When the function outputs random characters due to changing the `$string` variable right before decryption. I need to be able to detect that.

Comment: Why would you chaning the `$string` variable ?

Comment: if you are worried about your $string variable getting contaminated from other code, then you should create a class for your data and set your variable to private so that nothing outside your code can modify it. But only if it warrants an entire class, otherwise rename your variable to something really unique that isnt likely to get used in some other part of your code.

Comment: You are currently not using AES, you are using Rijndael with a *block size* of 256 bit, and a key size of 128 bit. MD5 is used as a password based key derivation mechanism, which it is not. The IV is not random, which is a requirement for CBC encoding, at least if you want to reuse the key.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Could you explain your comment? 1) Why did you say he is not using AES? (AES is not in the list of mcrypt ciphers in PHP manual). 2) What's wrong with Rijndael? 3) Also what's wrong with block size 256 + key size 128? 4) MD5 is clearly used here to get exactly 32bit length key, do you suggest it is incorrectly applied here? Why? 5) The IV is not random, why should it be? 6) What is the correct application of these functions according to you?

Comment: @Alph.Dev 1) AES is the standardized version of Rijndael with a block size of 128 bits and key sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bits, in mcrypt it is identical to MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128. 2) Rijndael is not standardized, so its not something you should use, especially if you want to be compatible with other libraries/runtimes. 3) It doesn't make much sense to use a large block size and small key size as the key size will determine the security (in CBC mode anyway) 4) MD5 outputs 128 bit of 16 bytes, even if you encode it afterwards as 32 hexadecimal *characters* 5) otherwise you are not CPA secure

Comment: @Alph.Dev 6) For CBC mode, see `mcrypt_encrypt` sample code in the official API that I (re)wrote. But better read my answer here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to detect tampering of the ciphertext is to add a MAC (message authentication code) over the ciphertext. This is a signature generated by a secret key. The key used for this should be different from the one used to perform the encryption. One way to do this is to use a KDF (key derivation function) over a master key to generate the two keys.

Alternatively it is possible to use an authenticated cipher such as GCM (Galois Counter Mode).

The authentication data generated by the MAC or by the authenticated cipher is called an authentication tag.

---

A reasonable implementation of what you are trying to achieve seems to be embedded in the Zend framework:

http://www.zimuel.it/en/english-cryptography-made-easy-with-zend-framework/

Don't forget to retrieve and store the salt together with the ciphertext (call `getSalt()` after encryption, use `setSalt()` during decryption). Note that the author confuses the word salt and IV often, which is not a good sign.

Disclaimer: I haven't read through the symmetric cipher code deployed by this component, and I haven't tested the code in any way.